# Visual Studio 2010 + XNA 4.0 Debug error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, xna

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for Windows 7 installed along with the Windows Phone Developer Tools (XNA 4.0). The installations went smoothly (no errors reported during install), but when I start debugging I get an error saying: "Attaching the ProteusDebugEngine debugger to process '[XXXX] projectname.exe' on machine 'MYCOMP' failed. Invalid Pointer"
However when I go to the debug menu and I choose start without debugging the program launches just fine. How can I fix this error? (Also everything works fine if I try debugging a Windows Phone Game... But when I try to debug an XNA 4.0 Windows Game I get the error message...)

EDIT:
When I start Visual Studio 2010 in safe mode and try to open a project it gives me an error and says that the project type is not supported by this installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling visual studio did not help.
Just reimaged then reinstalled and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the extended error message, there's usually a hint about which module crashed or isn't found, and it'll tell you to manually register it. Then try starting in safe mode to see if it works, because plugins that haven't been updated for XNA debugging can cause crashes. (Old versions of Resharper, for one.)

Comment: ive posted the error message above...
I have no idea what it means?!? :(

Comment: None of those are error messages, just the normal debugger messages with nothing out of the ordinary. I meant the crash window itself, which should have a "Details" button.

Comment: If you mean the window that opens up and shows the invalid pointer error the only button that shows up is 'ok' to clear the window...